# "Green Spire" shrub with no growth

Tags: shrubs, shade, growing-medium

"Green spire" vertical growing shrub not taking root very well, or growing at all. It was planted 4 weeks ago, nutrient rich soil, no problems except mininal morning sun. Ideas?

Comment: A photo would be helpful, but are you saying you only planted it 4 weeks ago? In the ground? Does it look healthy?

Answer (score 1):

There is a saying regarding woody plants: First year, they sleep; second year, they creep; third year, they leap. In other words No growth the first year, a little growth the second year, and typical growth (or slightly better than typical) the third year. Seeing no growth on any shrub four weeks after planting is typical and normal.